# WebApi GeoJson error serializing data

Tags: c#, json, serialization, asp.net-web-api, geojson

I have a web service trying to return GeoJson data, I keep getting this  error

> {"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"The
>   'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for
>   content type 'application/json;
>   charset=utf-8'.","ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException","StackTrace":null,"InnerException":{"Message":"An
>   error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"The method or operation is
>   not
>   implemented.","ExceptionType":"System.NotImplementedException","StackTrace":"
>   at GeoJSON.Net.Converters.GeometryConverter.WriteJson(JsonWriter
>   writer, Object value, JsonSerializer serializer)\r\n   at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeConvertable(JsonWriter
>   writer, JsonConverter converter, Object value, JsonContract contract,
>   JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty
>   containerProperty)\r\n   at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue(JsonWriter
>   writer, Object value, JsonContract valueContract, JsonProperty member,
>   JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty
>   containerProperty)\r\n   at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject(JsonWriter
>   writer, Object value, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty
>   member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty
>   containerProperty)\r\n   at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue(JsonWriter
>   writer, Object value, JsonContract valueContract, JsonProperty member,
>   JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty
>   containerProperty)\r\n   at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeList(JsonWriter
>   writer, IEnumerable values, JsonArrayContract contract, JsonProperty
>   member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty
>   containerProperty)\r\n   at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue(JsonWriter
>   writer, Object value, JsonContract valueContract, JsonProperty member,
>   JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty
>   containerProperty)\r\n   at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.Serialize(JsonWriter
>   jsonWriter, Object value, Type objectType)\r\n   at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.SerializeInternal(JsonWriter
>   jsonWriter, Object value, Type objectType)\r\n   at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(JsonWriter jsonWriter, Object
>   value)\r\n   at
>   System.Net.Http.Formatting.BaseJsonMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStream(Type
>   type, Object value, Stream writeStream, Encoding
>   effectiveEncoding)\r\n   at
>   System.Net.Http.Formatting.JsonMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStream(Type
>   type, Object value, Stream writeStream, Encoding
>   effectiveEncoding)\r\n   at
>   System.Net.Http.Formatting.BaseJsonMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStream(Type
>   type, Object value, Stream writeStream, HttpContent content)\r\n   at
>   System.Net.Http.Formatting.BaseJsonMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStreamAsync(Type
>   type, Object value, Stream writeStream, HttpContent content,
>   TransportContext transportContext, CancellationToken
>   cancellationToken)\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location
>   where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.WebHost.HttpControllerHandler.d__14.MoveNext()"}}

This is my controller

```
 // POST api/geo
    public List<GeoJSON.Net.Feature.Feature> Post([FromBody] locationsClass loc)
    {

        var lat = loc.lat;
        var lon = loc.lon;
        Geo Geo = new Geo();
        return Geo.GetRndNearybyLocationList(lat, lon, 400); 
    }
```

This is the method GetRndNearybyLocationList

```
        public List<GeoJSON.Net.Feature.Feature> GetRndNearybyLocationList(double lat, double lon, int meters)
    {
        LocationObject thisRndLocation = new LocationObject();
        List<LocationObject> locationsList = new List<LocationObject>();

        //List<GeoJSON.Net.Geometry.GeographicPosition> Positions = new List<GeoJSON.Net.Geometry.GeographicPosition>();

        Random rnd = new Random();
        int dice = rnd.Next(1, 7);
        List<GeoJSON.Net.Feature.Feature> featureList = new List<GeoJSON.Net.Feature.Feature>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= dice; i++)
        {
            thisRndLocation = getLocation(lat, lon, meters);

            GeoJSON.Net.Geometry.GeographicPosition latlon = new GeoJSON.Net.Geometry.GeographicPosition(thisRndLocation.lat, thisRndLocation.lon, 0);
            GeoJSON.Net.Geometry.Point point = new GeoJSON.Net.Geometry.Point(latlon);
            Dictionary<string, object> properties = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            properties.Add("Color", "Blue");
            GeoJSON.Net.Feature.Feature feature = new GeoJSON.Net.Feature.Feature(point, properties);
            feature.Id = "FeatureId: " + i;
            featureList.Add(feature);

            //var coOrdinates = new GeoJSON.Net.Geometry.GeographicPosition(thisRndLocation.lat, thisRndLocation.lon);
            //Positions.Add(coOrdinates);
            //locationsList.Add(thisRndLocation);
            //var x = locationsList;

        }
        return featureList;
    }
```

In fiddler I get the error , this is my Ajax

```
   $.ajax({
            type: 'Post',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: 'http://localhost:8506/api/' + 'Geo' + '/?alloworigin=true',
            data: JSON.stringify({ lat: lat, lon: lon }),
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    var obj = data[i];
                    console.log(obj.id);
                }
            },
            error: function (msg) {
                alert(msg.responsetext);
            }
        });
```

Things I have tried
Updgraded newtonsoft to version 6

adding this line to application_start

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
```

override in the Register method of the WebApi Config:

```
 var json = config.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
    json.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects;
    config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
```

So far no good, any ideas anyone ? , thx

here's the fixed class, ensure you use the correct base GeoJSon

```
namespace GeoJSON.Net.Geometry
{
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Newtonsoft.Json;



/// <summary>
/// In geography, a point refers to a Position on a map, expressed in latitude and longitude.
/// </summary>
/// <seealso cref="http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html#point"/>
public class Point : GeoJSONObject, IGeometryObject
{

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="Point"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="coordinates">The Position.</param>
    public Point(GeoJSON.Net.Geometry.GeographicPosition coordinates)
    {
        if (coordinates == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("coordinates");
        }

        this.Coordinates = new List<GeoJSON.Net.Geometry.GeographicPosition> { coordinates };
        this.Type = GeoJSONObjectType.Point;
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="Point"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="coordinates">The Position.</param>
    public Point(List<GeoJSON.Net.Geometry.GeographicPosition> coordinates)
    {
        if (coordinates == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("coordinates");
        }

        this.Coordinates = coordinates;
        this.Type = GeoJSONObjectType.Point;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the Coordinate(s).
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The Coordinates.</value>
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "coordinates", Required = Required.Always)]
    //[JsonConverter(typeof(PositionConverter))]
    public List<GeoJSON.Net.Geometry.GeographicPosition> Coordinates { get; private set; }
}
```

}

Comment: A warning - geojson spec says that UTF-8 encoding is not valid for geojson because UTF-8 has a BOM sequence. Parsers can choose to accept it, but many (including OGR, the library used by QGIS and many others) will fail with a parse error on UTF-8 encoded geojson. OGR appears to have no plans to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me that the library for GeoJSON has not yet implemented the write method. If we pop over to the [source for that file](https://github.com/jbattermann/GeoJSON.Net/blob/master/src/GeoJSON.Net/Converters/GeometryConverter.cs) at github then we can see that it is, in fact, not implemented yet. However there are some forks of the project which do seem to have implementations in place. You might try downloading the code for [mapbutcher's fork](https://github.com/mapbutcher/GeoJSON.Net) and building it.

Comment: Cheers, will give it a try be back soon

Comment: Bravo, well done that worked, hit another issue, my co-ordinates are null, must be adding them wrong, cheers for the tip, now to try and work how to do the points properly

Comment: GeoJSON.Net.Geometry.GeographicPosition latlon = new GeoJSON.Net.Geometry.GeographicPosition(thisRndLocation.lat, thisRndLocation.lon, 0);
            GeoJSON.Net.Geometry.Point point = new GeoJSON.Net.Geometry.Point(latlon);

Comment: Seems to be ignoring GeoJSON.Net.Geometry.GeographicPosition(thisRndLocation.lat, thisRndLocation.lon, 0);

Comment: This is a shame it's remmed out, there's a bug in the point.cs file

Comment: this.Coordinates = new List<IPosition> { coordinates };

Comment: cracked it fixed the class, i have no idea if I've done this right, use at your own risk

Comment: ensure you use the fork as linked by stimms, code updated, see point.cs, pls shout if you spot something badly wrong , will add to git if all is OK and post link here